# how to find the time taken for each testcase in Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara, watir

I am using Rspec in my project where I would like to print the time taken by each testcase, Is there any way Rspec is providing any prebuilt function? I can take the starting time of the testcase by `example.execution_result.started_at` but I don't know how to take the end time of testcase, If I can take the end time, then I can subtract the end time from starting time to get the time duration for each testcase. Is there any one help me at this place? I have written this code

```
around(:each) do |example|
  startTime=Time.now
  var=example.run
  puts var
  endTime=Time.now
  duration=endTime-startTime
  puts "Time Taken->#{duration.to_f/60.to_f}"
end
```

But I strongly believe Rspec must be giving some predefined method to return the duration of each testcase, do you anyone know that?

Comment: rspec can print 10 slowest specs, with their execution times. Is that good enough for you? Or you need this for _all_ specs?

Comment: The number 10 is configurable via the `profile_examples` setting. So if all you need is to see all the times you can just it to a number more than the number of tests - https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/configuration/profile-examples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want more detail and/or want to control the formatting, you can create a custom formatter.

For example, given the following specs:

```
RSpec.describe 'some thing' do
  it 'does stuff' do
    sleep(3)
    raise('some error')
  end

  it 'does more stuff' do
    sleep(2)
  end
end
```

**Output - Text**

We can add a custom formatter to output the full test description, status, run time and exception:

```
class ExampleFormatter < RSpec::Core::Formatters::JsonFormatter
  RSpec::Core::Formatters.register self

  def close(_notification)
    @output_hash[:examples].map do |ex|
      output.puts [ex[:full_description], ex[:status], ex[:run_time], ex[:exception]].join(' | ')
    end
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.formatter = ExampleFormatter
end
```

This gives us:

```
some thing does stuff | failed | 3.010178 | {:class=>"RuntimeError", :message=>"some error", :backtrace=>["my_spec.rb:21:in `block... (truncated for example)
some thing does more stuff | passed | 2.019578 |
```

The output can be modified to add headers, have nicer formatting, etc.

**Output - CSV**

The formatter can be modified to output to a CSV:

```
require 'csv'

class ExampleFormatter < RSpec::Core::Formatters::JsonFormatter
  RSpec::Core::Formatters.register self

  def close(_notification)
    with_headers = {write_headers: true, headers: ['Example', 'Status', 'Run Time', 'Exception']}
    CSV.open(output.path, 'w', with_headers) do |csv|
      @output_hash[:examples].map do |ex|
        csv << [ex[:full_description], ex[:status], ex[:run_time], ex[:exception]]
      end
    end
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.add_formatter(ExampleFormatter, 'my_spec_log.csv')
end
```

Which gives:

```
Example,Status,Run Time,Exception
some thing does stuff,failed,3.020176,"{:class=>""RuntimeError"", :message=>""some error"", :backtrace=>[""my_spec.rb:25:in `block...(truncated example)"
some thing does more stuff,passed,2.020113,
```

Comment: Hi, could you please include the header and neat formatting of possible ? Especially it looks as if in your first answer output ? If you are not willing , its okay. But it would be very helpful if you do this.

Comment: @Rajagopalan, do you need to actually output as text or can you use a CSV file?

Comment: Yes I can use CSV file so that I can open that in Excel file. Can you help me?

Answer (score 10):

RSpec has a example_status_persistence_file_path configuration that generates a file with the run time for each individual test.

For example, given the following RSpec configuration/examples:

```
require 'rspec/autorun'

# Enable the reporting
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.example_status_persistence_file_path  = 'some_file.txt'
end

# Run some tests
RSpec.describe 'some thing' do
  it 'does stuff' do
    sleep(3)
  end

  it 'does more stuff' do
    sleep(2)
  end
end
```

A report of each example's status and run time is generated:

```
example_id      | status | run_time     |
--------------- | ------ | ------------ |
my_spec.rb[1:1] | passed | 3.02 seconds |
my_spec.rb[1:2] | passed | 2.01 seconds |
```

Comment: Hey, this is an amazing info for me. But I want some more info, Can I change the first column instead of this `my_spec.rb[1:1]` this `does stuff` and Instead of this`my_spec.rb[1:2]` this `does more stuff`? Can I ? and also Can I add one more column as Error for Error message?

Comment: @Rajagopalan it sounds like what you really want is to just implement a custom formatter - https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-8/docs/formatters/custom-formatters

Comment: @Rajagopalan, as far as I know, there are no configuration options available. You can take a look through the code at https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/example_status_persister.rb

Comment: To expand on @ThomasWalpole suggestion, the JSON formatter outputs the description and run time. You can either use that formatter and parse the JSON results or use it as a starting point for a custom formatter.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole Thank you very much. I will have a look at this.

Comment: @JustinKo Okay, let me check it.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole To be frank, I don't know how to do, it simply printing example: my example I can bring one more output like example: my exampleexample: should But what I want is, I want the output which JustinKo posted but the first COLUMN consists of the testcase name do stuff and do more stuff rather than example id and also I want to add one more column named Error in which I want to print the result of example.exception, Is it possible? Will you post an answer for me?

Comment: @Rajagopalan, added another answer if you want to go the custom formatter route.

Answer (score 2):

Every example gets an ExecutionResult object which has a `run_time` method, so `example.execution_result.run_time` should give you what you’re asking for

Comment: No this run_time method is returning `nil` but If I call method `started_at` then it's printing `2018-12-03 16:06:42 +0530`

Comment: `require 'rspec'

describe 'My behaviour' do

  it 'test' do
    sleep 10
    puts 'Raja'
  end

  after do |example|
    p example.execution_result.run_time
  end
end` You can run this example and check it out. It's returning nil.

Comment: @Rajagopalan That's because inside the `after(:each)` the test is still actually ongoing and the finish time hasn't been set yet.

Comment: If so, May I know why are suggesting me to use this method? I did not get you exactly, Can you explain?

Comment: @Rajagopalan Because you asked what method RSpec provides for the test time and that is the method. You would need to adjust your around or after  blocks order using `pretend/append_after/around` to get it executed last so the time is set, however as I mentioned on the other answer it sounds like you really want a custom formatter which would get called with the values set

Answer (score 0):

Add one line to the `spec/rails_helper.rb` file:

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.profile_examples = true
end
```

After `rspec` has finished running it will display total run time (and time of each test)